# How can I access the value of a variable using it's JsonProperty attribute in a C# class?

Tags: c#

I have this class:

```cs
public class Configuration
{
   [JsonProperty("B_C.Parameter.fixtureHeight")]
   public string BCParameterfixtureHeight { get; set; }
}
```

I want to access the value of `BCParameterfixtureHeight` using its JsonProperty name of `B_C.Parameter.fixtureHeight`.

I've tried this which I think should work:

```cs
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.BCParameterfixtureHeight = "1";

var a = [config].GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => 
p.GetCustomAttributes<JsonPropertyAttribute>().Any(at => 
at.PropertyName.Equals("B_C.Parameter.fixtureHeight")));
```

However, I'm getting a `"Compiler Error CS1525"` and a red line under the opening bracket in [config].  The compiler is saying

> "Invalid expression term '['."

Comment: Why did you put config in square brackets?

Comment: When I remove the [], I get errors CS0308 "the non-generic method cannot be used with type args" and CS 1061 "object does not contain a definition for 'PropertyNamee" so I thought I was on the right track by adding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brackets you put around `config` are the problem.

You should write:

```
var a = config.GetType() //...
```

**EDIT:**

As Chris Schaller mentionned in the comments, you can fix your initial errors by giving the expeted arguments to `GetCustomAttributes`.

```
     var a = config.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => 
        p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute), false).Any(at => at is JsonPropertyAttribute && (at as JsonPropertyAttribute).PropertyName.Equals("B_C.Parameter.fixtureHeight"))
     );
```

Comment: Although slightly different syntax, you can see a proof here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BmppHG

Comment: When I remove the [], I get errors CS0308 "the non-generic method cannot be used with type args" and CS 1061 "object does not contain a definition for 'PropertyNamee" so I thought I was on the right track by adding them.

Comment: @Jeff check your code spelling, `PropertyNamee` has an extra `e`.

Comment: Call me old-fashioned, but I really dislike when a boolean expression is compared to true or false., it's superfluous, the boolean expression in itself is enough. So, I would remove == true.

Comment: @PalleDue you are right. It is worthless here and worse decreases the readability. I remove it